# Reversible math function that looks random

Tags: math, encryption, integer

I want a math function y = f(x) where x and y are 32 bit integers, such that

1. it is reversible by some function x = g(y)
2. the sequence f(1), f(2), f(3), ... looks random

I thought about XOR with some constant key, but that fails to look random.  Also I could use DES or AES.  But those seem like overkill.

Is there something simpler?

Comment: Some terminology is in order: a truly invertible function f: A -> A is called a *permutation* on A. So you want a "random" looking permutation on the space of 32-bit integers. There are a zillion ways to construct such a thing, so you will need to be even more specific. You can use AES or DES or Blowfish as examples, and shrink everything by a fact of 4 for AES or 2 for blowfish and DES, and use only a couple of rounds just as an example.

Comment: I smell an XY problem...

Comment: Try a block cipher such as Skip32. But note that this does always encrypt one value to another value, so you need to remember that repetition of the input leads to repetition of the output, possibly leaking information to the adversary.

Comment: Define "looks random"

Comment: @JohnColeman the idea is that it is difficult to predict the value f(n) given f(1) ... f(n-1) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark you are correct. i'll try to avoid this in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a block cipher such as Skip32. But note that this does always encrypt one value to another value, so you need to remember that repetition of the input leads to repetition of the output, possibly leaking information to the adversary.

Otherwise you can have a look at format preserving encryption. There are ways of halving the size of a block cipher such as 3DES, which has a significantly higher security margin (112 bits if you use three random keys), e.g. using a Feistel Network.

A weird cipher is the Hasty Pudding Cipher, which has a configurable block size. However, the security of that cipher is questionable and not researched enough at the very minimum.

Answer (score 1):

After asking this question, I found a different solution (appending a hash to my sequential key).  But it's still an interesting question. And I think the best answer is to implement a simple block cipher algorithm. There are several [examples here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/29836/16587).