# Generate a deterministic random number from a timestamp

Tags: random, rust

I’m generating IDs with a timestamp part (48 bits) and a random part (80 bits) so that the IDs are ordered but don’t clash. When serializing the IDs to a human readable format I want the IDs to *appear* random. The serialization will need to be reversible since I need to deserialize an ID back into its ordered timestamp/random form.

I don’t need the serialization to be secure, it’s ok if it’s easily reverse-engineered, I just want the appearance of a randomly generated ID.

Example of some IDs in hexadecimal that I want to encode:

```
16CF304F7B3D5CBED3977C90DD6F5
16CF30578DCBCF35A0585A4FF6DE0
16CF30599F53BB7E61791824D6345
```

Because of the ID format, I need an approach that will work on 128 bit values.

Comment: Why can't you use the IDs you have generated as is, as opposed to obfuscating them in an insecure way?

Comment: Aesthetics, otherwise every ID starts with the same sequence of characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reversible math function that looks random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973990/reversible-math-function-that-looks-random)

Comment: That question only appears to address 32 bit values, but I need an approach for 128 bit values.

Comment: The approaches described in the possible duplicate question can be adapted to values of arbitrary size, not just 32 bits.  In general, a reversible operation from N-bit integers to N-bit integers is called a _permutation_, and as a comment to that question states, "there are a zillion ways" of specifying that permutation.

Comment: What platform/language do you have in mind? Not all of them support 128bit math

Comment: The current platform is Rust but I imagine needing to adapt this to JavaScript. I recognize there are a bunch of ways to write the function and I’m struggling to explore the options which is why I’m asking on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the lowest bits are random, here's a very fast solution:

```
fn mix (x: u128) -> u128 {
    (x << 64) ^ x
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bcb91a62f0636810c9601be9276a7c3b)

The function is its own reverse, so `mix (mix (x)) == x`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could construct 128bit [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). With proper constants (see [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-00996-5/S0025-5718-99-00996-5.pdf) for details) it would map one 128bit value into another. Also, LCG support bijective mapping, so from result you could recover previous value.

Some (untested) C code, GCC or Clang

```
const unsigned __int128 a = 52583122484843402430317208685168068605;
const unsigned __int128 c = 1;

unsigned __int128 next(unsigned __int128 xprev) {
    return a*xprev + c;
}
```

Mapping guaranteed to be unique and bijective. If this is what you want, I'll dig out and post my reversal code.

In Javascript, 128bit LCG as direct mapper would look like

```
const WIDTH = 2n ** 128n;
const MASK  = WIDTH - 1n; // to keep things as 128bit values
const a     = 52583122484843402430317208685168068605n; // see L'Ecuyer paper
const c     =                                      1n; // see L'Ecuyer paper

function direct(xprev) { // takes BigInt argument
    return (a*xprev + c) & MASK; // same as % WIDTH
}

console.log(direct(BigInt('0x16CF304F7B3D5CBED3977C90DD6F5')))
console.log(direct(BigInt('0x16CF30578DCBCF35A0585A4FF6DE0')))
console.log(direct(BigInt('0x16CF30599F53BB7E61791824D6345')))
```

which produced the output (Win 10 x64, Node 12.7)

```
128874473614597675792465454982924903202n                                                                             
316384656665826187699254518510547678817n
104036942349128451345253863137794883122n
```

UPDATE

Digged out my skip code and converted it to Javascript

```
const WIDTH = 2n ** 128n;
const MASK  = WIDTH - 1n; // to keep things as 128bit values
const a     = 52583122484843402430317208685168068605n; // see L'Ecuyer paper
const c     =                                      1n; // see L'Ecuyer paper

function direct(xprev) { // takes BigInt argument
    return (a*xprev + c) & MASK; // same as % WIDTH
}

// Signed argument - skip forward as well as backward

// The algorithm here to determine the parameters used to skip ahead is
// described in the paper F. Brown, "Random Number Generation with Arbitrary Stride,"
// Trans. Am. Nucl. Soc. (Nov. 1994). This algorithm is able to skip ahead in
// O(log2(N)) operations instead of O(N). It computes parameters
// A and C which can then be used to find x_N = A*x_0 + C mod 2^M.
function skip(x, ns) { // takes BigInt argument

    let nskip = BigInt(ns);

    let aa = a;
    let cc = c;

    let a_next = 1n;
    let c_next = 0n;

    while (nskip > 0n)
    {
        if ((nskip & 1n) != 0n) {
            a_next = (a_next * aa) & MASK;
            c_next = (c_next * aa + cc) & MASK;
        }

        cc = ((aa + 1n) * cc) & MASK;
        aa = (aa * aa) & MASK;

        nskip = nskip >> 1n;
    }

    return (a_next * BigInt(x) + c_next) & MASK;
}

function inverse(x) {
    return skip(x, MASK);
}


console.log(direct(BigInt('0x16CF304F7B3D5CBED3977C90DD6F5')));
console.log(direct(BigInt('0x16CF30578DCBCF35A0585A4FF6DE0')));
console.log(direct(BigInt('0x16CF30599F53BB7E61791824D6345')));

console.log('\n');
q = BigInt('0x16CF304F7B3D5CBED3977C90DD6F5');
console.log(q);
r = direct(q);
console.log(r);
t = inverse(r);
console.log(t);
```

Last three prints produced

```
7402051076614138449931424144152309n                                                                                                                    
128874473614597675792465454982924903202n                                                                                                               
7402051076614138449931424144152309n
```

Comment: Would this require the space for 2^128 values? Since this will be used on many nodes in a distributed system I need it to be fast and space efficient.

Comment: @Calebmer No, what you see is what you get. Space requirements are quite limited, circa 3 128 bit values per mapper.